# Potential U&L impact from TOS change on Imgur

Tags: discussion

I've just become aware of [Imgur TOS change on May 15th 2023 could cause the loss of thousands of Stack Exchange images!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388556/imgur-tos-change-on-may-15th-could-cause-the-loss-of-thousands-of-stack-exchange), which quotes:

> We will be focused on removing old, unused, and inactive content that is not tied to a user account

Stack Exchange has [a corporate version of Imgur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424280/4957508), whose links include `i.stack.imgur.com`, leaving open the possibility that images which are  hosted on Imgur *outside* of that URL could be removed.

Based on [this search for url `https://imgur.com` and score>= 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3ahttps%3a%2f%2fimgur.com%20score%3a1&searchOn=3) on U&L, there are currently 109 posts (with a score above zero) that include links to `https://imgur.com`.

How should we address this potential change?

Comment: The “obvious” quick fix doesn’t work: pasting an imgur.com link to re-add the image on SE’s instance results in “Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server”.

Comment: We have [288 posts with links to `https://i.imgur.com` and score ≥ 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com+score%3A1) which would also be affected.

Comment: I've done a couple edits. I'm wondering if we tackle the highest-scored and highest viewed posts, if that would save the most useful information. There's a debate about flooding the front page with edits, but a random sampling just now shows the front page turns over in about 7 hours, so that would be a temporary problem.

Comment: ... and I forgot about Unix.Meta!

Comment: It's also possible to check which URLs are archived at the wayback machine https://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php and send a list of URLs to archive e.g. at https://web.archive.org/save , so the images can be recovered later and reuploaded.

Answer (score 3):

Barring any better ideas, I'm going to suggest that any interested editors (preferably those >= 2k to ease the suggested edit barrier) tackle the affected posts. Please refer to [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388726/307535) that contains the results of an automated upload of existing images. Edits can use the Replacement URL for the affected posts, sparing a download and upload cycle.

Since time is running (relatively) short, I'd suggest tackling the highest-scoring posts first. Live search links follow:

- [Posts with links to `https://i.imgur.com`, score >= 1, sorted by score](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3ahttps%3a%2f%2fi.imgur.com%20score%3a1&searchOn=3)
- [Posts with links to `https://imgur.com`, score >= 1, sorted by score](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3ahttps%3a%2f%2fimgur.com%20score%3a1&searchOn=3)

If you're motivated, I see no reason to curb your enthusiasm in order to keep the home page clean; it appears to turn over within 6-7 hours, so edit to your heart's content!

Comment: It would be smart to focus on images that Glorfindel's script *couldn't* re-upload, as the ones that *did* get uploaded will be there after the 15th.